# Launch an NSTask and bring it to front

Tags: objective-c, nstask

I'm trying to launch another application using NSTask

```
NSArray* argArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fileName, nil];
NSTask* task = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:appName arguments:argArray];
```

while this works the main gui window doesn't come to front.

when repeatedly calling with different fileName the new file does get loaded in the app even though only 1 instance of the app is running

any poiners? I did try `SetFrontProcess` but seems to have no effect even after introducing a delay

I did look into NSRunningApplication but it seems it is not available on 10.5 whereas I need a solution for both 10.5 and 10.6

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `NSTask` to launch applications. Use [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which has several methods (e.g. `-launchApplication:`) to launch and activate an application.

Comment: There is a problem with using NSWorkspace I want to pass a file name as the argument in NSWorkspace functions if the app is already running meaning new instance is not created the argument part is ignored which makes it unusable in this scenario

Comment: Well in that case, maybe launch the app using NSTask and then use one of the NSWorkspace launching methods right after, because the NSWorkspace methods will bring the application to the front if it is already running.

Comment: @user549164: You can provide `NSWorkspaceLaunchNewInstance` to always launch a new instance, if that's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed these from my `MDFoundationAdditions` and `MDAppKitAdditions` categories.

This solution should work for Mac OS X 10.4.x and later (which is when LSOpenApplication() was introduced):

MDAppKitAdditions.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "MDFoundationAdditions.h"

@interface NSWorkspace (MDAdditions)
- (BOOL)launchApplicationAtPath:(NSString *)path
          arguments:(NSArray *)argv
            error:(NSError **)error;
@end
```

MDAppKitAdditions.m:

```
#import "MDAppKitAdditions.h"
#if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED <= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_4
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#elif MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#endif

@implementation NSWorkspace (MDAdditions)

- (BOOL)launchApplicationAtPath:(NSString *)path arguments:(NSArray *)argv
             error:(NSError **)error {
    BOOL success = YES;
        if (error) *error = nil;

        if (path) {
            FSRef itemRef;
            if ([path getFSRef:&itemRef error:error]) {
                LSApplicationParameters appParameters =
                  {0, kLSLaunchDefaults, &itemRef, NULL, NULL,
                (argv ? (CFArrayRef)argv : NULL), NULL };

                OSStatus status = noErr;
                status = LSOpenApplication(&appParameters, NULL);

                if (status != noErr) {
                    success = NO;
                    NSLog(@"[%@ %@] LSOpenApplication() returned %hi for %@",
                        NSStringFromClass([self class]),
                        NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), status, path);
                    if (error) *error =
        [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:status userInfo:nil];
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}
@end
```

MDFoundationAdditions.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

@interface NSString (MDAdditions)
- (BOOL)getFSRef:(FSRef *)anFSRef error:(NSError **)anError;
@end
```

MDFoundationAdditions.h:

```
#import "MDFoundationAdditions.h"
#import <sys/syslimits.h>

@implementation NSString (MDAdditions)

- (BOOL)getFSRef:(FSRef *)anFSRef error:(NSError **)anError {
    if (anError) *anError = nil;
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    status = FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8 *)[self UTF8String], anFSRef, NULL);
    if (status != noErr) {
        if (anError)
    *anError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:status userInfo:nil];
    }
    return (status == noErr);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the task you want to launch is a proper application, you can use NSWorkspace's

```
- (BOOL)openFile:(NSString *)fullPath withApplication:(NSString *)appName
    andDeactivate:(BOOL)flag
```

Comment: I've tried this but there seems to be a problem in passing arguments which have ' ' spaces int like a long file path with spaces. I tried passing in with quotes but the function returns an error

Comment: the app doesn't open file if there are spaces in filename

Answer (score 0):

To expand on indragie's answer, if you want a new instance launched with a file argument, do something like (untested):

```
NSDictionary *config = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSArray arrayWithObject:filePath], NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments,
                         nil];
NSError *error = nil;
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:yourAppURL options:NSWorkspaceLaunchNewInstance | NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault configuration:config error:&error]
```

On 10.5, you might try (not tested):

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObject:fileURL] withAppBundleIdentifier:@"com.foo.someapp" options:NSWorkspaceLaunchNewInstance | NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault additionalEventParamDescriptor:nil launchIdentifiers:nil];
```

Comment: NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments is only available in 10.6 or later

Comment: Then you'll probably have to use `launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:...` and construct your own Apple Event to pass in the file.

Comment: other app doesn't have a bundle identifier :(

Comment: Is it an older app? I don't think I've come across one without a bundle identifier in a while…